# Least upper bound of open domains

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**: Prove that for any family $\{U_s\}_{s\in S} $ of open domains in a topological space $X$ the set $\text{Int}(\overline{\cup_{s\in S}U_s})$ is the least upper bound.

**Definition**: A subset $U$ of a topological space satisfying the condition $U=\text{Int}\overline{U}$ is called an open domain.

**Attempt**: Assume the contrary that is $\exists$ $r\in S$ such that $$\text{Int}(\overline{\cup_{s\in S}U_s})\subset U_r=\text{Int}(\overline{U_r})$$
$$\iff$$
$$\overline{\cup_{s\in S}U_s}\subset \overline{U_r}$$
$$\iff$$
$${\cup_{s\in S}U_s}\subset {U_r}$$

Contradiction.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, just apply straightforwardly the definition of least upper bound in a poset, as I sketched below.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U:= \operatorname{Int}(\overline{\bigcup_{s \in S} U_s})$.

- First show that $U$ is an open domain.
- Then show $U_s \subseteq U$ for all $s \in S$.
- Finally show that if $V$ is an open domain and $U_s \subseteq V$ for all $s$ we have $U \subseteq V$.